# Highchart - why "this.series.name" does not work?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've been working on a Highstock.

Why when I do "this.series.name" (in  tooltip: {formatter:...}) I got an error "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" ?
Whereas "this.x" work.

Example of the problem:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
      // work:
         //var s = '<b>' + this.x + '</b>';
      // does not work:
         var s = '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b>';

        $.each(this.points, function () {
            s += '<br/>1 USD = ' + this.y + ' EUR';
        });

        return s;
    }
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2sssgfLz/

Doc of the API:
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.formatter

Comment: Try to do a `console.dir(this)` and see exactly what properties you have in there.

Comment: `this` is declared in an anonymous function - therefore it is not referencing the object (which you are attempting to do)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pointFormatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormatter)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbudh5u4/)

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormatter: function () {
      //console.log(this); 
     /*use this to see various data including series name in array. when using Formatter tooltip option only x and y values are there. so error comes.So use pointFormatter to get series name in tooltip*/
      var s = '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b>';
      s += '<br/>1 USD = ' + this.y + ' EUR';
      return s;
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: usdeur
    }]
```

is an array, so you should use `this.series[0].name`.

Answer (score 0):

What I see with the log :

```
Object:                                                               
  points: Array(1)
    0: Object
      color:"#69A942"
      ...
      series: r
         ...
         name: "..."
         ...                                                               
  x: 1492740120000                                                         
  y: 0
```

**But for the tooltip it's :**

```
Object:                                                               
  series: r
      name: "..."                                                            
  x: 1492740120000                                                         
  y: 0
```

So I got the error "Cannot read property '0' of undefined" for each flags when I do :

```
if(this.points[0].series.name !== 'Changement de référence' ){...}
```

I would like do an if condition which check if "this.series.name" exist and if it is not egal to "..." (something)

I tried :

```
if(typeof this.series.name != "undefined" && this.series.name != 'Changement de référence'){
```

It does not work, have you got an idea ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.points[0].series.name`, example below.

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
          var s = '<b>' + this.points[0].series.name + '</b>';

            $.each(this.points, function () {
                s += '<br/>1 USD = ' + this.y + ' EUR';
            });

            return s;
        }
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: usdeur
    }]
});
```

Live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/7revy1dn/